# How to configure otphp for Microsoft Authenticator App?

Tags: php, one-time-password, two-factor-authentication, authenticator

I am working on a Laravel project and want to create an own 2-Factor-Authentication with One Time Passwords.

So I chosed [Spomky-Labs otphp library](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp) and have some code like this:

```
$secretB32 = Base32::encode('slkopnucji6vl34utmehqla5mbkb4grvmet7uvs7dtnko6v4bqwhfk3v');
$otp = TOTP::createFromSecret($secretB32);
$otp->setDigest('sha1');
$otp->setPeriod(60);
$otp->setLabel('Project name');
$otp->setDigits(6);
// Echos the provisioning URI to make QR code from.
echo $otp->getProvisioningUri();
echo '<br /><br />';
// Echoes the six digits One Time Password
echo $otp->now(); // Works with FreeOTP App but not with Microsoft Authenticator
```

The QR code resulting from the provisioning URI works perfectly fine with the [FreeOTP](https://freeotp.github.io) App, but it does not work with the Microsoft Authenticator App which I'd prefer due to its way more professional look.

Microsoft Authenticator does not even recognize the 60 seconds period. I assume that I setup Spomky's lib incorrectly, especially the algorithm.

Did anyone made this work? Thanks in advance!

PS: I am open to any other PHP library as well.

Comment: I did a bunch of work with OTP (including this same Spomky-Labs library) a few years ago and discovered that the vast majority of the client-side apps only supported the default parameters of 6 digits, 30 seconds, SHA1 hash. FreeOTP was the only one I found that supported anything else.

Comment: FWIW [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lmOtQaS4If-Ez89MJo701rVVVD--l-CXBkV2iCmEUL8/edit?usp=sharing) are the results of all my tests. (Note this is at least 5 years old, so YMMV.) I didn't bother testing every box because the pattern became pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks @AlexHowansky, I guess I've been too stupid to test.

Comment: No, not stupid at all, I did the same thing. I think it's totally reasonable to expect a TOTP implementation to work with more than just these exact three settings.

Comment: @iquellis Don't add your solution to the question or mark posts as "solved" in the title. It belongs as an Answer, in the big box below. Stackoverflow is a Q&A side, remember! See also [answer]. I've rolled back your change so you can post an answer instead. If you need to retrieve what you wrote, see the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78142411/revisions). Without an answer in the right place nobody will find your solution anyway because search engines will perceive your question as unanswered, and nobody can vote on the answer's usefulness either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vast majority of OTP apps only support the default parameters of 6 digits, 30 seconds, SHA1 hash. FreeOTP is the only one I found that supported everything I threw at at, with 1Password a close second. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lmOtQaS4If-Ez89MJo701rVVVD--l-CXBkV2iCmEUL8/edit#gid=0) is a grid I made a few years ago, showing all the combinations I tried.

If you don't mind requiring your users to use a specific OTP app, you can use values other than these defaults.

If you don't want to impose this restriction on your users, keep your parameters at 6 digits, 30 seconds, and SHA1 hash.